# Is an infinite sum of positive measures a positive measure?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $\{\nu_j\}$ is a sequence of positive measures. Then is $\sum_1^{\infty} \nu_j$ also a positive measure.

This came across my mind, while solving a problem that says "If $\nu_j \perp \mu$ for all $j$, then $\sum \nu_j \perp \mu$ and if $\nu_j << \mu $ for all $j$, then $\sum \nu_j << \mu$.

But for this problem to make sense, $\sum \nu_j$ should also be a measure. I tried checking the second condition, that is, let $\{E_k\}$ be a sequence of disjoint measurable sets, then $\sum_j \nu_j (\cup E_k)=\sum_j (\sum_k \nu_j(E_k))$. I need to show that this last sum is equal to $\sum_k (\sum_j \nu_j(E_k))$ but I cannot guarantee, or I don't know if it can be guaranteed that the sums can be interchanged in this case.

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: If I recall correctly, it's exactly when the terms of the series are positive that you can reverse the order of the double sum.

Comment: You need to show $\sum_j \nu_j (\cup E_k) = \sum_k (\sum_j \nu_j(\cup E_k))$  and you can reverse summation by Fubini's Theorem since terms are non-negative

Comment: Yes, check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini's_theorem#Tonelli.27s_theorem_for_non-negative_functions".

Comment: You have $\sum_j (\sum_k \nu_j(E_k))=\sum_k (\sum_j \nu_j(E_k))$, because the for all $j$ and $k$,  $\nu_j(E_k)\geqslant 0$.   Although this is a special case of Fubini-Tonelli theorem, you DON'T need use this theorem, because this spacial case is directly proved for series in most of the introductory analysis textbooks.